# Change word in dataframe to different word from different dataframe if they match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have some trouble with my dataframe comparison. What I have are two dataframes, the first has tokenised words.

```
df_1:
id  sentence               some more info 
1   [I, am, happy]         bla 
2   [I, am, happier]       bla 
3   [I, am, the, saddest]  bla
```

and

```
df_2:
id word   more     most 
1  happy  happier  happiest 
2  sad    sadder   saddest
```

What I want to do is compare the two dataframes and if a word in df_1 matches a word anywhere in df_2 that it will be changed to df_2['word'] in the row of the corresponding word. So my output would look something like this:

```
df_1
id  sentence               some more info new_sentence
1   [I, am, happy]         bla       [I, am, happy]
2   [I, am, happier]       bla       [I, am, happy]
3   [I, am, the, saddest]  bla       [I, am, the, sad]
```

I have tried some things using .compare() and writing a function, but nothing has seemed to work so far.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary from second `DataFrame` by remove `id` column, reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
d = df.drop('id', axis=1).melt('word').set_index('value')['word'].to_dict()
```

And then map values in `dict.get` with return same values if no match:

```
df_1['new_sentence'] = df_1['sentence'].apply(lambda x: [d.get(y, y) for y in x])
```

Or:

```
d = df.drop('id', axis=1).melt('word').set_index('value')['word'].to_dict()

df_1['new_sentence'] = [[d.get(y, y) for y in x] for x in df_1['sentence']]
```